# Windows Terminal not showing in Win + X menu on fresh Windows 11

Tags: windows, microsoft-surface, windows-11, windows-terminal

I have just received my Surface Pro 8 running Windows 11 that I pre-ordered. After setup, Windows Terminal does not appear to be installed. Therefore, I went to the Microsoft Store to download the application. I have downloaded it, and it works as expected, but it does not appear in the Win + X menu (right-click windows logo), see [figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Kt4.png).

I have previously owned the Surface Pro 7, which I installed the Windows 11 beta on, and I knew that it has "Windows Terminal" and "Windows Terminal (Admin)" on the Win + X menu. It looked like this (see [figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLdRs.jpg)).

While researching this matter, I found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10595) GitHub Issue for Windows Terminal. The only different thing is that this is for Windows 11 and Windows Terminal STABLE, not Preview/Insider.

Is there any way to fix this without reinstalling Windows 11 from scratch? I have already tried restart, uninstall Terminal and reinstall.

Figure 1 is my own image, Figure 2 is a screenshot from [here](https://gearupwindows.com/how-do-i-make-windows-terminal-always-open-with-command-prompt-on-windows-11/).

Comment: I will look around. Right now I have both a Windows 11 Pro Production and a Windows 11 Pro Insider machines. Win+X shows Terminal in Both. Vanilla installations.

Comment: Based on the issue you linked to this is likely a Windows 11 bug that might or might have already been fixed in a cumulative update. However, due to the most recent message (yesterday) indicating it might have only been solved internally, I have my doubts about it being fixed. Be sure you have 22000.168 installed which was released on November 4th 2021. Likewise, be sure you have the stable version of Windows Terminal installed instead of the preview build as that appears to be the underline issue with the Win+X functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a short adaptation of the procedure from the article
[Add or Remove Default Shortcuts on Win+X Quick Link Menu in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-default-shortcuts-on-win-x-quick-link-menu-in-windows-11.1007/).

- Download from the article the file
  [WinX.zip](https://www.elevenforum.com/attachments/winx-zip.5886/)
- Unzip the file (this might require unblocking it)
- Open an Explorer instance and position to the folder
  `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3`
- Delete all icons in this folder (or copy elsewhere for backup)
- Copy here the contents of `Group3` sub-folder from the unzipped file
- Sign out and sign back in.

The article has more details with screenshots that might help.